# Multiple ActiveX buttons visible/hidden

Tags: vba

I have a Worksheet in excel 2013, with 25 activex buttons on it. depending on a cell value for each button, i would like it to be visible or hidden. In my case the value of cell U6 makes my commandbutton1 visible, U7 would make commandButton2 visible.... Only my CommandButton1 works properly. I have tried different combinations of code without succes.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'ActiveX button1
       If Range("U6") = 1 Then
        Sheets("Feuil1").CommandButton1.Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("Feuil1").CommandButton1.Visible = False
      End If

   End Sub
```

Comment: That code _does_ look like it would work just fine for making `CommandButton1` visible if `Range("U6")=1`. What have you tried for the other buttons that _isn't_ working, and how do you define "isn't working"? Are you getting an error? Not getting the results you expected? Something else?

Comment: So... you're showing us the code that's working, and asking why the code we're not seeing isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> If Range("U6") = 1 Then
> ```

Shouldn't that check if the `Target` (i.e. the modified cell) is in column U?

> ```
> Sheets("Feuil1").CommandButton1.Visible = True
> ```

That road leads to pastaland, you don't want to go there: extract a method. You'll want to query the `OLEObjects` collections to get the ActiveX control by name, rather than hard-coding the button names 25+ times.

```
Private Sub SetControlVisibility(ByVal controlName As String, ByVal isVisible As Boolean)
    Dim axControl As OLEObject
    On Error Resume Next 'next statement may throw error #9
        Set axControl = Me.OLEObjects(controlName)
        If axControl Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0 'restore error handling
    axControl.Object.Visible = isVisible
End Sub
```

Now you have a method that can toggle the visibility of any ActiveX control on the sheet, given its name.

So in the `Worksheet_Change` handler, you now just need to work out the name of the ActiveX control, and whether or not you want it visible:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'bail out if the modified cell isn't interesting, or if it's more than 1 cell:
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("U6:U31") Is Nothing  Or Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim buttonName As String
    buttonName = "CommandButton" & Target.Row - 5

    Dim isVisible As Boolean
    isVisible = Target.Value = 1

    SetControlVisibility buttonName, isVisible
End Sub
```

Or something like it. Note: code written in the answer box, untested & for illustrative purposes only. Copy-pasta at your own risk.